# php strtotime return 1970-01-01

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = 'MAY 05, 2001  00:54:00 AM';

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($a)).'<br />';

$b = 'MAY 05, 2001  05:54:00 AM';

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($b)).'<br />';

//MAY 05, 2001  00:54:00 AM return 1970-01-01
//MAY 05, 2001  05:54:00 AM return 2001-05-05

?>
```

Comment: so what do you want to do.. you didnt tell what you exactly needed

Comment: <?php
$a = 'AUG 09, 2013  08:13:00 PM';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($a)).'<br />';
//return 2013-08-09 20:13:00

$b = 'AUG 29, 2013  04:60:00 PM';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($b)).'<br />';
//return 1970-01-01 07:00:00
?> that'it

Comment: Do you want hours / minutes/seconds to be displayed here.. the code you showed is working good.. and whats wrong

Comment: many time are 12 hour clock need convert to 24 hour clock as you see AUG 22, 2013 03:60:00 PM return 2013-08-09 20:13:00 this works fine but AUG 29, 2013 04:60:00 PM return 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: ... Tell me; Have you ever seen ´04:60´ on your alarm clock? If so, it's broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AM` implies you are using a [12-hour clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock). However, there is no "zero hour" in this clock system, so your first time example of `00:54:00 AM` is not a valid time (12-hour clock runs from one to twelve, then flips back to one with am/pm switched). Perhaps you meant just `00:54:00` (24-hour clock) or `12:54:00 AM/PM` (which would be six minutes before one o'clock).

Comment: not that way: <?php
$a = 'AUG 22, 2013  03:60:00 PM';
$b = 'AUG 29, 2013  04:60:00 PM';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($a)).'<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($b)).'<br />';
?>

Comment: @miket: those dates are invalid too, because there is no such thing as a sixtieth minute. The minute after `04:59:00` would be `05:00:00`, not `04:60:00`. Some very lenient date/time parsers might accept wacky formats like the examples you provided but it's only natural that it would be rejected.

Answer (score 2):

You have passed AM in 24 hour time format.I have corrected it

```
$a = 'MAY 05, 2001 00:54:00';

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($a)).'<br />';

$b = 'MAY 05, 2001  05:54:00 AM';

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($b)).'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a PHP version later than 5.3.0 you can use

http://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.date-parse-from-format.php

like

```
$a = 'MAY 05, 2001 00:54:00';

echo date('Y-m-d',date_parse_from_format("F d, Y H:i:s",$a)).'<br />';
```